# Generating the sequence of the digits that appear in the sequence of natural numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, generator

This is a revisit to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995418/python-generator-expression-vs-yield) already asked here about a year and a half ago.

Project Euler's [Problem 40](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=40) involves generating the sequence of digits that appear in the natural numbers, all concatenated together (`123456789101112131415161718192021…`).  As part of the solution, I wrote this:

```
def counting_digits():
    for number in count(1):
        for digit in str(number):
            yield digit
```

After finishing the solution, I tried this:

```
def counting_digits():
    return (digit for number in count(1) for digit in str(number))
```

My questions:

1. In the face of Python 3, Which solution is more *pythonic*?
2. As someone who just wants to understand the code. Which is easier/clearer to read?
3. If you haven't read the statement for Project Euler's [Problem 40](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=40), Which version lets you better know what the function does?

Performance is not part of the question: *pythonism* and understandability is the issue.

Comment: As a programmer who is somewhat familiar with Python, but writes it fairly infrequently, I find the `yield` version more readable.

Comment: @Matt But isn't the _yield_ concept harder to grasp unless you come from Ruby or such?

Comment: Since you didn't do any operation on `c`, the last one makes more sense.

Comment: How about `yield int(c)`?

Comment: I already understand what `yield` does from JavaScript, but JS doesn't have generator expressions. I don't know Ruby. I find that the extra white space in the `yield` version is just plain easier on the eyes. It's all a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Matt _easier on the eyes_: It's my own code, and, hoopla, I have to think harder to understand what I wrote in the generator expression version.

Comment: I think generator expressions are only useful when they are simple enough that they don't need explanation and you can use them inline in whatever your code is doing. The moment you want to move into its own function the yield syntax is clearer.

Comment: The first is easier to read, and hence more Pythonic. There should also be no difference in performance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The one where you return a generator is easier to read were it the case that there was only one `for`. Also, as OP pointed out, the associativity of nested for loops is not what you'd expect in Python.

The top one may be slightly easier to read for some people; it would be MUCH easier to read if there were comments or if the variables were semantically named, and the indented structure allows for comments much better. With semantically-named variables, the first version is easier to read; I'd only use single-letter variable names as the pattern in list comprehensions.

Comment: In which case(s) is the generator more efficient?

Comment: In the case of nested generators, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys/6043835#6043835 where I mention asymptotic speed.

Comment: That's not so much an issue with yielding though, as it is with re-yielding, so perhaps not that applicable.

Comment: @ninjagecko I edited the variable names.

Comment: It seems that the double `for` is the killer, because Python's way of determining scope (the earlier `for` dominates the following one) is unusual. You'd expect the result to be more closely related to the `for` that is closer.

Comment: @Apalala: oh my, that is incredibly awkward... I had never noticed that. Wish I could upvote your comment more... I wonder what the rationale for the very awkward ordering in nested `for`s is...

Comment: @ninjagecko As I said in the question's text, just edit your answer, and make my comment yours. The insight is yours, after all.

Answer (score 10):

Someone who doesn't know Python would look at the first version and ask "What's yield do?"  After a quick google search of "python yield" they'd easily grok it.

The same person would look at that second version and say "WTF?"  What would we expect them to google to understand it?

I won't speak for the Python community at large, but as an experienced Python programmer I find the first version clearer and more pythonic.  When I encounter nested generators or list comprehensions I still need to stop for a moment to puzzle it out.  I think the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) concede that nested generators and list comprehensions can be confusing when they advise

> To avoid apprehension when nesting
>   list comprehensions, read from right
>   to left.

And shortly after that they say

> In real world, you should prefer
>   built-in functions to complex flow
>   statements.

Comment: +1 As I mentioned, it was unexpected for me that right after writing this question, I found that my own code was harder to understand in the single-liner version.

Answer (score 4):

"pythonic" and "easier/clearer" is a completely subjective issue.

The first example is more readable and understandable - even for a Java developer.
The second piece of code is more dense but I would not call it pythonic.
Both pieces of code are fine for me.

Comment: I think that Java doesn't yet support the concept of _yield_ (suspended/lazy execution). Why would the more 'structured code' version be clearer for a Java developer?

Comment: You are correct that Java doesn't support `yield`, but the `yield` version still _looks_ more like Java than the generator version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very subjective. In my case, I've used Python for about 9 months (albeit rather a lot) and find the syntax of the generator expression more concise and readable. Given the simplicity, using the generator inline would be preferable, in this case. If you needed something a bit more complicated, I'd lean towards a function.

Comment: I agree, except that I'd rather place the generator in a well-named function than place it inline and have to explain it with a comment.

Comment: @Apalala Maybe a good rule of thumb is to avoid using a generator expression when you feel it'd be necessary to add a comment explaining what it does. In this case I think a comment would be unnecessary.